# jQuery Mobile Collapsible firing at page load multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have this custom JS code for testing purpose :

```
    jQuery('#ReportedCollapsible').bind('expand', function () {
    alert('Expanded');
}).bind('collapse', function () {
    alert('Collapsed');
});
```

the #ReportedCollapsible has those attributes :

```
container.attr(
    "data-role",
    "collapsible"
).attr(
    "data-collapsed",
    "true"
)
```

Two problems here :

Even tough my data-collapsed is set to true (has shown in the code snippet), on page load, the alert "Expanded" pop ups like 6 times straight.

And, whenever I click on the collapsible, the alert "Expanded" or "Collapsed" do fire at the right sequence but it fires multiple times again.

What's going on ?

Thanks

Comment: you add it dynamically?

Comment: Yes, the collapsible set which contains multiple collapsible is created dynamically.

Comment: collapsible-set, expands and collapses. it opens a collapsible and closes a collapsible, hence, expand/collapse will be triggered simultaneously. by default, collapsibles are collapsed when they are initialized. I assume you have 6 collapsibles inside collapsible-set, that's why expand triggers 6 times. true? Please add your markup.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/psrgd/

Comment: Yup, found the problem it was in a for loop for each collapsible like you said. Thanks